# How to override HTTP header in request response?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I would like to modify HTTP headers of the request responses using `AFHTTPSessionManager` (the final goal is to modify the `Cache-Control` header in order to force caching).

I didn't find any delegate, block in order to do such things. Did I miss something? Maybe by subclassing `AFHTTPSessionManager`? Any idea how to do this the right way?

Regards,
Quentin

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you need

```
[sessionManager.requestSerializer setValue: maxAge forKey:@"cache-control"];
```

And you can use this for referring how to [set-up the header.](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9)

You can similarly set-up `sessionManager.responseSerializer`

Comment: Thanks but it partially answer my problem. In my case the server set the response HTTP headers to ` Cache-control: no-cache`. So the response data will never be cached (ie, the block set with setDataTaskWillCacheResponseBlock is never called) for this request (but it is called for others). This is why I would like to modify the response before all the AFNetworking HTTP stack stuff to get this block called. But maybe it is a bad pattern, and I should do this another way.